# Writing a python program that outputs the average of a group of numbers by the user

Tags: python

I have to write a python program that outputs the average of a group of numbers by the user, which I have successfully done in the code below. However, the code must also output the group number and the number of characters that the user has entered and this is the part that I'm stuck on. So for example, the output should look like this:

Group 1 has 5 numbers that average 4.98.

Group 2 has 27 numbers that average 97.81827365

Group 3 has 13 number that average 5983.19283

I also have to use while loops and sentinels and I'm not sure how to finish it. Any advice or assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
data = []
sum = 0
numberOfSentinels = 0
while numberOfSentinels < 2:
    number = int(input("Enter a data value or -1 twice to quit: "))
    if number != -1:
        data.append(number)
        sum += number
        numberOfSentinels = 0
    else:
        if numberOfSentinels == 1:
            break
        else:
            numberOfSentinels = 1
            print(data, "The average is ", sum/len(data))
            data = []
            sum = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = []
numberOfSentinels = 0
group = 1
while numberOfSentinels < 2:
    number = int(input("Enter a data value or -1 twice to quit: "))
    if number != -1:
        data.append(number)
    else:
        numberOfSentinels += 1
        if numberOfSentinels == 2:
            length = len(data)
            avg = sum(data)/length
            print("Group %d has %d numbers that average %s" % (group,length, str(avg)))
            group += 1
            data = []
            break
```

Comment: Thanks, but now the program only computes the average of one group after entering -1 twice and then it stops. It needs to be able to do multiple groups. That's the tricky part.

Comment: There has to be someway user wants to get out of the whole program, if you could tell me what is that then I can tweak program to work as you expect.

Comment: If the user enters -1 twice the program should quit. -1 is our sentinel value. otherwise the program needs to continue.

Comment: There are two exit points here: 1) Users exiting a group 2) User exiting the whole program. Entering -1 twice will cater to 1st exit point. You need something for the second exit point as well. You cant have same sentinel for two things.

Comment: Here are the instructions:

Comment: OUTPUT: A list of each group of numbers average, one per line. Each line will display 
the group index (an integer), the count of the numbers in the group (an integer), and 
the average of the numbers in the group (a float). Example output for 3 groups:

Group 1 has 5 numbers that average 4.98.
Group 2 has 27 numbers that average 97.81827365
Group 3 has 13 number that average 5983.19283